# Need Owner role for create dataset from Google Cloud Logging?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want to stream logs into BigQuery. I'm using the beta release of Google Cloud Logging. I can see the logs on browser. I got invalid role error when I set up streaming to BigQuery from Google Cloud Logging export view. My role is Edit role on this project.

What I did:

1. Open Google Cloud Logging page
2. Open export tab
3. Select source and BigQuery data set name.
4. I got the error "invalid role to see this page"

It worked normally when I tried it on another project. I have owner role of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a BigQuery dataset indeed only project EDIT role is needed.
However to create any export in Cloud Logging (not only to BigQuery), project OWNER is required.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export#prerequisites